# Can't get curves from FBX

Tags: animation, fbx, curves

I'm trying to obtain animation curves from fbx file with FBX SDK. I'm trying like it said in FBX docs: http://help.autodesk.com/view/FBX/2017/ENU/?guid=__cpp_ref__import_scene_2_display_animation_8cxx_example_html . Here's the code:

```
        int layersCount = currAnimStack->GetMemberCount(); 

    ///  layersCount = 1

        FbxAnimLayer* layer = currAnimStack->GetMember<FbxAnimLayer>(0);

    //// layer is ok, it's not null

        FbxAnimCurve* curve = inNode->LclTranslation.GetCurve(layer, FBXSDK_CURVENODE_COMPONENT_X);
        curve = inNode->LclTranslation.GetCurve(layer, FBXSDK_CURVENODE_COMPONENT_Y, NULL);
        curve = inNode->LclTranslation.GetCurve(layer, FBXSDK_CURVENODE_COMPONENT_Z, NULL);
        curve = inNode->LclRotation.GetCurve(layer, FBXSDK_CURVENODE_COMPONENT_X, NULL);
        curve = inNode->LclRotation.GetCurve(layer, FBXSDK_CURVENODE_COMPONENT_Y, NULL);
        curve = inNode->LclRotation.GetCurve(layer, FBXSDK_CURVENODE_COMPONENT_Z, NULL);

        curve = inNode->LclTranslation.GetCurve(layer, FBXSDK_CURVENODE_COMPONENT_X, NULL, false);
        curve = inNode->LclTranslation.GetCurve(layer, FBXSDK_CURVENODE_COMPONENT_Y, NULL, false);
        curve = inNode->LclTranslation.GetCurve(layer, FBXSDK_CURVENODE_COMPONENT_Z, NULL, false);
        curve = inNode->LclRotation.GetCurve(layer, FBXSDK_CURVENODE_COMPONENT_X, NULL, false);
        curve = inNode->LclRotation.GetCurve(layer, FBXSDK_CURVENODE_COMPONENT_Y, NULL, false);
        curve = inNode->LclRotation.GetCurve(layer, FBXSDK_CURVENODE_COMPONENT_Z, NULL, false);
```

But curve is always null, no matter how I try. At the same time, in 3ds Max curves are being displayed. So what may be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That operation during exporting from 3ds Max gave me the curves I need:

4. Go to Motion->Trajectories and press Collapse.